# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in the same folder project

Tags: python

I am working with python 3.6

I have a project folder called providers.

Inside providers I have two folders:

```
   ├── Providers
       ├── __init__.py
       |             
       ├── _config                    
       |   ├── database_connection.py             
       |   ├── __init__.py           
       ├── src             
       |   ├── overview.py      
       |   ├── __init__.py
```

I want to import a class named DatabaseConnection that is inside the file database_connection.py in the file ovewview.py

```py
# Overview.py
from _config.database_connection import DatabaseConnection
```

But I receive this error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_config'
```

Comment: You can use `..` to tell Python to "back up" one directory level: `from .._config.database_connection import DatabaseConnection`

Comment: Then I obtain this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: I believe you also need an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `Providers` directory.

Comment: I have, I have modified the question for add it

Comment: Perhaps it's because `src/__init.py` has the wrong name?  It should be `__init__.py`.

Comment: No, I wrote it wrong in the question, in the code is well written

Comment: Hmm.  How is `overview.py` being executed?  Are you running it directly with `python Providers/src/overview.py`?  Or is it being imported from somewhere else?

Comment: I am running it with `python Providers/src/overview.py`

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  I thought I understood this, but apparently not...